# Are there any laws or regulations regarding hosting Canadian Government websites?

Tags: internet, canada

> Many industry and governmental security and data protection regulations and laws include specific requirements regarding where data can and must be kept.

This quote is from [clouda.ca](https://www.clouda.ca/data-privacy-canadian-data-residency/) which is a web hosting service among other things. No matter what I search for online I can't seem to find any specific laws or requirements. Most of the time I get redirected to the PIPEDA act which doesn't seem to contain the information I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you not understand? What exactly is the information that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The *Personal Information Protection and Electronic Documents Act* (or PIPEDA) is a Canadian federal statute governing the use of personal information and other sensitive data. It applies to all private sector organizations, as well as federal government agencies. There is also provincial legislation in place that has been declared substantially similar to the aforementioned act.

Your quote is essentially a marketing message. If there is an organization that collects personal information in the country, then it must stay in Canada - it cannot be hosted in any of country. The site is basically saying that they are compliant with federal privacy regulations.

You can't host a "government website." I have no clue what you're saying there.

Comment: We are being paid to design and then manage a provincial website. The group we met with to discuss the features of the website pointed out that they "probably fall under some government laws regarding where the website is hosted". The PIPEDA restrictions mostly deal with collecting and storing user information. I am trying to find what other "laws and regulations" we are subject to as quoted from clouda.ca. Sorry if the question was poorly worded, this is my first post on stack exchange.

Comment: @Adam That's okay! The only issue is this - I need to know exactly what's going on that website, the audience of the website and so on. It may be worth pointing out that you're *designing* the website, not providing competent legal input. You need to get a lawyer for this stuff - I'm very sure you do not want to get legal advice from a high school student.